# Symfony web server inside container causing issue when restarting

Tags: php, linux, docker, symfony

I run a Symfony application inside a container. It work well but when I restart the container, the container exit with code 0. I can only do `docker kill container && docker rm container && docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name container image/path` in order to update the container.

Here a simplify version of my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2
    
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget -yq && wget https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer -O - | bash && mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin/symfony
COPY . /app
COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
CMD cd /app/ && symfony server:start --no-tls
```

with `docker restart container` the `docker logs` cmd return

```
[Web Server/PHP ] Jul 24 14:55:28 |INFO | PHP    listening path="/usr/local/bin/php-cgi" php="7.2.31" port=33139
[Web Server/PHP ] Jul 24 14:55:28 |DEBUG| PHP    started
[OK] Web server listening
The Web server is using PHP CGI 7.2.31
http://127.0.0.1:8000
[WARNING] The local web server is already running
Local Web Server
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
The Web server is using PHP CGI 7.2.31
Local Domains
Workers
No Workers
Environment Variables
None
```

and then, it exit whith with code 0.

So I try to stop the symfony web server before restarting but it doesn't work. I'm pretty confused because the problem cames from the CMD statement, but I can't really change it because I need to start the web server when I run the container. A possibility could be to run the symfony app on another web server like apache but using the symfony web server is pretty convenient, I don't think it's a best practice for production (but it's a personal project).

So I'm pretty confuse about why it doesn't work, if someone got an idea

Comment: What have you tried to debug the "issue"?

Comment: I'm sure the problem is the `symfony server:start` cmd. I've tried to launch a basic built in php server (`php -S ...`) and the container doesn't breaks on restart.  I log out the the container before it exited (it's in the question). I just don't understand why the server is already running. So I try to `symfony server:stop` before the CMD statement but it's ugly and it doesn't work. If you have some ideas to get more debug information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so running symfony server for production is a bad idea, I just create a new docker image based on php-apache image and everything works better

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is probably because of the cd command in your CMD. You should use WORKDIR instead and keep only the server start command in your CMD
I would also suggest the use of docker compose. You can find a full tutorial here https://knplabs.com/fr/blog/how-to-dockerise-a-symfony-4-project

Comment: No still the same problem, I'm currently using docker-compose.

Comment: @cannabear answer is still valid: you should switch to docker-compose and use an http server like nginx, following the tutorial he gave you